# does "Which" refer to the correct part of the sentence

Tags: word-usage

I learned that I can use **which** to joint two sentences instead of writing two separate sentences. Sometimes, I feel that, **which** does not refer to the correct part of my sentence. How can I know that I use **Which** correctly in my sentence? For example,

> A is the model part of method B, **which** requires the following conditions.

I feel that **which** here refers to method B instead of part A.

Do I use **which** correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction using **which** is ambiguous.

It does not make it clear whether **which** refers to the whole of the preceding main clause or just part of it.

To avoid this ambiguity you need to rephrase your sentence or to divide it into two sentences.

For example you could say:

> A is the model part of method B, a method which/that requires the following conditions.

or

> A, which requires the following conditions, is the model part of method B

depending on your meaning.

Or you could split it up, separating the clauses with either a semi-colon or a stop:

> A is the model part of method B; the method requires the following conditions

or

> A is the model part of method B; A requires the following conditions